# How do i prevent html/javascript code from running on a textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a chat application wirtten in javascript, when a user enters an html code like

```
 <button>click</button>
```

a button appears on chat. I use this code

```
 if(message.indexOf('<button') != -1)
            {   
              message = message.replace(message, '&#45;'); 
            }
```

but this just replaces the < button

with a blank space, I want it to be displayed  as text and not an actual button.

Thanks

Comment: That you have a chat application implies you've got serverside processing going on. Don't bother trying to amend the code at the upload stage (it's trivial to bypass and to run arbitrary javascript on a receivers machine). Clean the datastream on the server before re-broadcasting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general encode procedure here would be:

```
value = value.toString().replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/'/g, "&#39;").replace(/"/g, "&#34;");
```

Comment: Chain anything else you would like to encode, e.g. ampersand.

Answer (score 7):

I just use this:

```
message = message.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
```

That's all that's needed to prevent HTML from being inserted.

Answer (score 0):

what html element did you use for print the chat? try use textarea or pre tag.

try to control those errors in the back end because everybody can deactivate javascript.